# Implement Interface Wizard - how to find the "type library" of an interface?

Tags: visual-studio, atl

I want to implement (e.g) the IPersistFile interface via the "Implement Interface" Wizard in Visual Studio (2010), but I have to choose from the "Available type libraries" the one that has that interface. The MS documentation only says it is in "ole32.dll" (when I choose that file I get an error "No type library found in file ...").

How do I find which "type library" holds the (e.g) IPersistFile interface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some interfaces you can look up containing type via registry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\<IID>\TypeLib`, but note that an interface does not necessarily have to have a type library reference.

Comment: So how do I find it in the wizard ?

Comment: I suppose there is no type library for IPersistFile (for other interfaces registry lookup does just fine).

Comment: Yep - no library for IPersistFile, apparently no need to update the IDL (for that specific interface ? don't know..), so the way is the plain manual method of writing the code.